# Can I pass a variable into a form while declaring it in a view in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, dynamic, view

I have declared the following form

```
form = BudgetPageInitial()
```

in my `view.py`, what I want is to pass on a variable(say 'x') into the `BudgetPageInitial()`, so that I can use that variable in the forms definition in `forms.py` to generate 'x' number of input fields int he form `BudgetPageInitial`.

Please guide me to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**View**

```
form = MiscQuestionForm(request.POST or None, misc=misc_questions)
```

**Form**

```
class MiscQuestionForm(BootstrapForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        misc = kwargs.pop('misc')
        super(MiscQuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for question in misc:
            if question.answer_type == 1:  # bool
                self.fields['custom_%s' % question.pk] = forms.BooleanField(
                        label=question, required=True)
            else:  # textfield
                self.fields['custom_%s' % question.pk] = forms.CharField(
                        label=question, widget=forms.Textarea,
                        required=True)
```

This is the design pattern you can use to pass variables to your form definition as I have with `misc`.

Comment: i tried to implement the above. Initially it was not able to identify 'BootstrapForm' hence i replaced it with'forms.Form' but there are some issues in rendering the Template,can you plz show me how you have implemented the Template for this form.